# Issue creating Hive External table using tblproperties

Tags: hive

I am trying to create an external table with tblproperties in Hive. The table gets created but it does not display the rows. Any ideas? Please find the scripts i am using below:

Thanks for your time and suggestions in advance.

### Data is in a recursive folder: /user/test/test1/test2/samplefile.csv

```
use dw_raw;
drop table if exists temp_external_tab1;

create external table if not exists temp_external_tab1 (
col1 int,
col2 string,
col3 string,
col4 string
)
row format delimited fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n'
stored as textfile
location '/user/test/test1/'
tblproperties ("hive.input.dir.recursive" = "TRUE", 
    "hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories" = "TRUE",
    "hive.supports.subdirectories" = "TRUE", 
    "mapred.input.dir.recursive" = "TRUE");
```

Answer (score 3):

These are not table properties, but global settings.

You should set these using 'set', i.e.:

```
set hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories=true;
set mapred.input.dir.recursive=true;
```

Answer (score 1):

You've created a table but haven't put any data into it.  Try

```
hive> LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/user/test/test1/test2/samplefile.csv'
      INTO TABLE temp_external_tab1;
```

Comment: I am passing the path so if the recursive directory input is set to true shouldn't it scan all files in that location and add it to the table. If i use 'set property', instead of adding it to tblproperties the same above query results into table creation along with data population..

Comment: use dw_raw;
drop table if exists temp_external_tab1;

set mapred.input.dir.recursive=true;
set hive.supports.subdirectories = true;
set hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories = true;
set hive.input.dir.recursive=true;

create external table if not exists temp_external_tab1 (
col1 int,
col2 string,
col3 string,
col4 string
)
row format delimited fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n'
stored as textfile
location '/user/test/test1/';

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ambari the set the following properties to hive advanced config inside custom hive-site.xml.

SET hive.input.dir.recursive=TRUE

SET hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories=TRUE

SET hive.supports.subdirectories=TRUE

SET mapred.input.dir.recursive=TRUE

And then restart the affected services. This will read all the data recursively.