# Problems saving partitioned parquet HIVE table from Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, partitioning, parquet

Spark 1.6.0
Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.8.0

I have some problems saving my dataframe into parquet-backed partitioned Hive table from Spark.

here is my code:

```
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema)
df.write
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .format("parquet")
  .partitionBy("year")
  .saveAsTable(output)
```

nothing special, actually, but I can't read any data from the table when it's generated.

Key point is in partitioning - without it everything works fine.
Here are my steps to fix the problem:

1. At first, on simple select hive returns that the table is not partitioned. - Ok, it seems like Spark forget to mention about partitioning scheme in DDL. I fixed it creating the table manually
2. Attempt #2 - still nothing, what is going on actually, is that hive metastore doesn't know that the table has any partitions in dwh. Fixed it by:
   hive> msck repair table
3. Attempt #3 - nope, and now hive bursts with exception, smth like: java.io.IOException:ort.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: java.lang.NullPointerException. Ok, spark defined wrong serializer. Fixed it setting `STORED AS PARQUET`
4. Nope. Don't remember what exceptin it was, but I realized that spark replaced my scheme with single column:
   `col` array COMMENT 'from deserializer'
   I replaced it with corrent one - some another problem came out.

And here I'm done. To me it seems like spark generates totally wrong ddl trying to create non-existing table in hive. But everything works pretty fine when I just remove partition statement.

So where am I wrong or, perhaps, there is a quick fix to that problem?

Comment: Could it be the issue is with how Hive tries to read the directories? Unless you change a couple settings it won't recursively read the table directory. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767713/can-hive-recursively-descend-into-subdirectories-without-partitions-or-editing-h