# HIVE Parquet error

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to insert the content of a dataframe to a partitioned parquet-formatted hive table using

```
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).insertInto(myTable)
```

with `hive.exec.dynamic.partition = 'true'` and `hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = 'nonstrict'`.

I keep getting an `parquet.io.ParquetEncodingException` saying that

> empty fields are illegal, the field should be ommited completely
>   instead.

The schema includes arrays (`array<<struct<<int, string>>>>`), and the df do contain some empty entries for these fields.

However, when I insert the df content into a non-partitioned table, I do not get an error.
How to this fix this issue.

I have attached error [image: error screenshot]

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767713/can-hive-recursively-descend-into-subdirectories-without-partitions-or-editing-h) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38784450/problems-saving-partitioned-parquet-hive-table-from-spark?rq=1) might help. similar questions.

Comment: this is a know issue,  empty arrays and maps cause these problems (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-11625)

Comment: how do i fill the empty spaces in arrays. I know fillna works with string but not with arrays.