# Hive external tables not able to see partitioned Parquet files

Tags: apache-spark, hive, partitioning, parquet

I am generating Parquet files (partitioned by `setid`, using Snappy compression) using Spark and storing them at a HDFS location.

```
df.coalesce(1).write.partitionBy("SetId").
  mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).
  format("parquet").
  option("header","true").
  save(args(1))
```

Parquet Data file is stored under `/some-hdfs-path/testsp`

I then create the Hive table for it as follows:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE DimCompany(
  CompanyCode string,
  CompanyShortName string,
  CompanyDescription string,
  BusinessDate string,
  PeriodTypeInd string,
  IrisDuplicateFlag int,
  GenTimestamp timestamp
) partitioned by (SetId int)
STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION '/some-hdfs-path/testsp'
TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count'='1','parquet.compress'='snappy');
```

However, when I select on table in Hive, it doesn't show any results.

I tried:

1. running `msck` command like:

   ```
   msck repair table dimcompany;
   ```
2. setting the following:

   ```
   spark.sql("SET spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet=false")
   ```

None of those are working, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your partition column, `SetId`, uses **upper-case** letters.

Since Hive converts its column names into lowercase, your partition column is stored as `setid` instead of `SetId`. Thus, when Hive searches for partitions/folders in a case-sensitive data store, it looks for `setid=some_value` and finds nothing, since your data folders are of the format `SetId=some_value`.

To make this work, convert `SetId` to lower case or snake_case. You can use this by aliasing the column in your DataFrame:

```
df.select(
... {{ your other_columns }} ...,
col("SetId").alias("set_id")
)
```

You may also have to set these properties before executing the create statement, based on this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767713/can-hive-recursively-descend-into-subdirectories-without-partitions-or-editing-h)

```
SET hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories=TRUE;
SET mapred.input.dir.recursive=TRUE;
```

After you create your table, also try running

```
msck repair table <your_schema.your_table>;
```

Comment: Ran into this problem myself - credit for root cause goes to Anuvrat Singh's article on [Medium](https://medium.com/a-muggles-pensieve/hive-partition-column-name-camelcase-bad-idea-bc203d6e65da)