# How to access files in nested directory structure in hdfs?

Tags: bigdata

I have a directory named `/abc` which contains some csv files and my external hive table points to that directory.

Now the `/abc` directory contains one more directory `/def` which contains some csv files too.

How will I access all the files ?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767713/can-hive-recursively-descend-into-subdirectories-without-partitions-or-editing-h